# Stop one function and toggle another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I've set up two sets of looping functions to animate an svg vertically or horizontally. I want to toggle which animation is running on every click, therefore I need to stop/kill the the function that is currently triggered and call the alternative 'Up' function. How can I go about doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated

```js
var Rightscale = {
    svgEl: $('#right').find('svg'),
    svgH: $('#right').find('.scale').height(),
    svgW: $('#right').find('.scale').width(),
    cntH: $('#right').height(),
    cntW: $('#right').width(),

    init: function() {
        Rightscale.svgEl.on("click", function() {
            Rightscale.verticalUp(Rightscale.svgEl)
        });
    },
    verticalUp: function($elt) {
        var scaleH = Rightscale.cntH / Rightscale.svgH;
        $elt.css('transform', 'scaleY(' + scaleH + ')')
        setTimeout(function(){
            Rightscale.verticalDown($elt);
        }, 5000);
        
    },
    verticalDown: function($elt) {
        $elt.css('transform', 'scaleY(1)')
        setTimeout(function(){
            Rightscale.verticalUp($elt);
        }, 5000);
    },
    horizontalUp: function($elt) {
        var scaleW = Rightscale.cntW / Rightscale.svgW;
        $elt.css('transform', 'scaleX(' + scaleW + ')')
        setTimeout(function(){
            Rightscale.horizontalDown($elt);
        }, 5000);
    },
    horizontalDown: function($elt) {
        $elt.css('transform', 'scaleX(1)')
        setTimeout(function(){
            Rightscale.horizontalUp($elt);
        }, 5000);

    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    Rightscale.init();
});
```

```css
#right {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.scale {
    font-size: 0px;
    width: 40%;
}
svg {
    transition: transform 5000ms linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="right">
<div class="scale">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
        viewBox="0 0 392 132" style="enable-background:new 0 0 392 132;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
        <path d="M81.2,117.5c-6.6,8.8-17.5,13-34.8,13c-17.7,0-28.6-4.3-35.2-13.9c-5.3-7.5-7.7-17.1-8.5-32.4c-0.2-4.3-0.4-9.8-0.4-16.6
            c0-18.4,0.9-27.3,3.6-37.3C7.2,25.5,9.2,21,11.7,17C18.5,6.7,29,2,45.6,2c17.3,0,27.9,3.8,34.6,12.4c7.9,10.2,10.4,22,10.4,51.2
            C90.6,93.4,87.9,108.1,81.2,117.5z M57.4,66.1l-0.2-16.4C56.9,24,56.1,21.9,46.9,21.9c-6.2,0-9.4,3.4-10.2,10.9
            c-0.6,7.5-0.9,21.8-0.9,38.4c0,13,0.2,25,0.8,29.4c0.8,6.2,4.1,9.4,10,9.4c5.6,0,9-3.2,9.8-9.6c0.6-4.5,1.1-19.2,1.1-31.1V66.1z"/>
</g>
    </svg>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a handle to the TimeOut that you want to stop:

```
    verticalDownTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        Rightscale.verticalDown($elt);
    }, 5000);
```

and you can stop it with

```
clearTimeout(verticalDownTimeout);
```

I'll leave the details to you, I trust you can handle it.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help. Unfortunately your trust was misguided. What I'm struggling to understand is how to evaluate which timeout has been called so that I can target it with the clearTimeout()

Comment: When you activate one timeout, just stop all others.

Comment: Or just stop all tiemouts before setting a new timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching an event listener to the element inside of the init() function. What you need to do is to remove the existing event listener and add another one. So first you need to pass it not as an anonymous function but as a named callback so you can remove it with `.off` method.

You need to transform you event listeners into closures that can accept the element and return functions like so:

```
verticalUp: function($elt) {
    return function() {
        var scaleH = Rightscale.cntH / Rightscale.svgH;
        $elt.css('transform', 'scaleY(' + scaleH + ')')
        setTimeout(function(){
            Rightscale.verticalDown($elt);
        }, 5000);
    }        
}
```

Then you can add event listeners like this:

```
init: function() {
    Rightscale.svgEl.on("click", Rightscale.verticalUp(Rightscale.svgEl));
}
```

Then you can add your logic for removing the listeners, but the syntax would be the following:

```
Rightscale.svgEl.off("click", Rightscale.verticalUp(Rightscale.svgEl));
Rightscale.svgEl.on("click", Rightscale.verticalDown(Rightscale.svgEl));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use key frames so that the vertical up does not need to call the vertical down. and onclick i would change the svg's current keyframe from animate vertical to animate horizontal. the jquery Finnish method is useful if you don't want to refactor.

```js
state: true,

init: function() {
        var scaleH = Rightscale.cntH / Rightscale.svgH;
        $.keyframe.define([{
            name: 'vertical',
            '0%':   {'transform', 'scaleY(1)'},
            '50%': {transform:'scaleY(' + scaleH + ')')},
            '100%': {'transform', 'scaleY(1)'}
        }]);
        
        var scaleW = Rightscale.cntW / Rightscale.svgW;
        $.keyframe.define([{
            name: 'horizontal',
            '0%':   {'transform', 'scaleX(1)'},
            '50%': {transform:'scaleX(' + scaleW + ')')},
            '100%': {'transform', 'scaleX(1)'}
        }]);
        
        
        Rightscale.svgEl.on("click", function() {
            //stop the current animation and any future animation que 
            //https://api.jquery.com/finish/
            Rightscale.svgEl.finish();
            Rightscale.svgEl.playKeyframe({
              name: Rightscale.state ? 'vertical':'horizontal',
              duration: 10 * 1000
            });
            Rightscale.state = !Rightscale.state;
        });
    },
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I am trying to achieve. However, after adding the [jQuery.Keyframes](http://keyframes.github.io/jQuery.Keyframes/) library and clearing up the syntax I am still unable to get it working at all

Comment: Where is the init function called?

Comment: I feel dumb.  I'll be able to look at it indepth later today.